# jQuery Tabs - get tabtemplate of selected tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have 3 tabs. Tab1 is selected by default. If I click Tab2; I want to get the previous selected tab.

I tried:

```
var previousTab;

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
            select: function (event, ui){
            doSomething(previousTab);
            previousTab = jQuery(ui.tab);
            },
            create: function (event, ui) {
            previousTab = jQuery(ui.tab);
        }
    });
});
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone tell me the solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `show` function.
`previousTab` is a variable in global scope.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function (event, ui) {
            previousTab = jQuery(ui.tab);
        },
        show: function (event, ui) {
            previousTab = jQuery(ui.tab);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that, at `create`, `ui` is an empty object. If you know first tab is selected at start, you can simply assign the previous tab variable to the first tab at `create`.

One suggestion: instead of creating a global variable to keep track of the previous tab, you can store it in the `#tabs` element. It is generally a good practice to avoid creating variables in the global scope.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var previousTab = $(this).data('previousTab');
        if (previousTab !== undefined)
            console.log(previousTab);
        $(this).data('previousTab', $(ui.tab));
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).data('previousTab', $($(this).find('ul > li > a').get(0)));
    }
});
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/yMbhA/2/.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have also found a way to do it. But yours seems nice.

Comment: In that case, it's probably more appropriate to call it `currentTab`. ;)